# ValueErorr: Graphdef cannot be larger than 2GB

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

The error is thrown by https://github.com/rajkumarcm15/Medical-Image-Segmentation/blob/master/PixelWise/train_class.py#L254 the place where I save the model after being trained. How can I overcome this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines inside your training loop create new reshape ops on *every iteration*. So if you run 1000 iterations you'll have 2000 reshape ops added to the graph, which can very quickly make the graph definition exceed the 2Gb limit (unfortunately this size limit comes from Protobufs and can't easily be increased). Try moving these ops (and anything else tf.*) outside your loop.

`train_data = sess.run(tf.reshape(train_data, [-1, 1, _x_, _y_, _z_]))
train_targ = sess.run(tf.reshape(train_targ, [-1, 1, 3, 1]))`